# In vim, is there a way to cancel a search *without* resetting the cursor position?

Tags: vim

In vim, I've got the `hlsearch` and `incsearch` options turned on. When I start a search, it immediately goes to the first match. If I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept the search, the result is highlighted and the cursor is positioned at the first match. If I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to cancel, the cursor position is reset to wherever I was when I started the search.

Is there a way in this case to make <kbd>Esc</kbd> cancel the search but leave the cursor position on the first match? That way I'd end up in the right spot but without anything highlighted.

Thanks!

Comment: One day I turned off hlsearch and I never went back. You might think you want it more than you actually do. You can always turn it back on temporarily if you really need to highlight something.

Comment: There's a problem with your idea: if you cancel the search it means that you don't want to perform it. In that case there's no reason for the cursor to move to the first match: no search, no move.

Comment: A common mapping is to use `<c-l>` which redraws the screen to also clear highlighting: `nnoremap <silent> <C-l> :noh<CR><C-l>`. If your terminal can handle it mapping `<esc>` is also nice: `nnoremap <silent> <esc> <esc>:noh<cr>`

Answer (score 3):

I added this to my .vimrc:

```
:command C let @/=""
```

I like search highlights, I just don't like them to stick around, so when I'm done with it, I can just type `:C` and they go away!

Also I changed my highlights to underlines instead of selection-esq styled which is easier on my eyes, but still easy to pick out multiple matches on a page without having to blindly `n` over and over.  Best of both worlds imo.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `:nohl` after hitting `<Enter>` to cancel the highlighting.

You could make it easy to switch between highlight mode and non-highlight mode by using a mapping:

```
" put this in your vimrc
nnoremap <Space> :set hls!<CR>
```

Alternately, you could use a mapping to clear out the current search term.

```
" put this in your vimrc
nnoremap <Space> :let @/=""<CR>
```

Comment: Right, but doing this every time I search is a huge pain. I use search like this to move around a file -- goal is to make it as quick as possible.

Comment: Devin Lane: You could use a mapping to make it easier.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:nohlsearch` to temporarily remove the highlighting; from `:h :nohlsearch`:

> #### `:noh[lsearch]`
>
> Stop the highlighting for the `hlsearch` option.  It is automatically turned back on when using a search command, or setting the `hlsearch` option.

You could easily map this to whatever you want, I happen to use `<leader>h`:

```
nmap <silent> <leader>h :nohlsearch<CR>
```

Of course, you must first hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to exit search mode before you can hit the mapping, but it quickly becomes habitual to hit the mapping keys afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I making an assumption that you really want a quick way to toggle between highlighting the search pattern and not highlighting.  I say this because pressing `enter` is one way to quit the search that keeps the cursor at the current position whereas `escape` quits in a way the cursor is reset to where it was before the search.

So to toggle highlighting (without using `<leader>`) you could put the following in your .vimrc file (I have a bunch of toggle Boolean values in my .vimrc file that all begin with \t):

```
nmap \th :set invhls<CR>
```

Then all you have to do to go from highlighting to not highlighting is:

```
\th
```

Other toggle mappings I use are for Booleans `spell`, `number`, `ignorecase`, `paste` and `wrap`.

Once you are more comfortable with vim you can start using `<leader>`.

Comment: I'd rather not have to press extra keys to turn off a mode I didn't want to turn on in the first place (the search), but thanks for pointing out `<leader>` -- wasn't aware that existed.

Comment: I’m not really sure what you mean “without using `<leader>`”, one could easily define `<leader>` to be `\ `, and then make your mapping as `map <leader>th` and it would be exactly the same as what you have…

Comment: Do you just want to turn off `hlsearch`?  You said you had it on, but it sounds like you do not like it.  If you like it on when you are searching, but like it off after the search is complete, the best solution is a quick way to toggle the option.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @Andrew Marshall, I find the use of `<leader>` confusing to people learning vim.  So I try to avoid its use in answers.

Comment: @cforbish I’d argue that you’re just misleading people into thinking it’s this mystical and complicated thing that one should avoid. Plenty of explanation is just a few keystrokes away at `:h <leader>`.

Comment: @cforbish Here's the thing: If I'm actually searching for something, then I want to see the highlight as I step through the results. But if the search immediately gets me to where I want, or close enough, I want to immediately switch to normal/edit mode *with the cursor on the search term* without the distracting highlight. If there was a way to make canceling the search just not reset the cursor position that'd be perfect.

Comment: @Devin Lane I guess you want to see all the matches highlighted while searching.  You should get the current search highlighted if `nohls` and `incsearch` are set.  Is this correct?

Comment: @cforbish I don't get the search highlighted if I have `nohls` set.

Comment: I get a different color highlight (in my case white instead of red) if I have `incsearch` and `nohls` turned on.  Besides the color, the only other difference is only one pattern is highlighted (not all on the page).  I cannot think of a setting that will get you seeing what I am seeing.